# How to use Socket.io in node while handling http server externally

Tags: node.js, http, socket.io

I have a web application running on node.js, and I want to use socket.io to send data to the client when my database is updated.

The problem is, most solutions I have found involve adding lines to `app.js` like:

```
var app = express()
var http = require('http')
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server)
```

But my server implementation is handled in an external js file (`http-server.js`), as below:

```
import http from 'http'
import app from '../lib/app'

class HTTPServer {
    constructor(app) {
        this.app = app
    }

    create(options) {
        this.server = http.createServer(this.app)

        this.server.on('error', err => {
            console.log(`HTTP:   ${err}`)
            throw err
        })

        this.server.listen(options.port)
    }
}

export default new HTTPServer(app)
```

And in my PUG template I have:

```
var socket = io()
socket.on('hello', function(msg) {
        console.log(msg)
});
```

So I have been having trouble setting up the socket in `app.js` as when I have:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log("connected")
    io.emit('hello', "hello world")
})
```

The client throws a 404 error.

> GET http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MXBmiMH 404 (Not Found)

I have tried

```
const app = express()
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

and

```
import HTTPServer from '../lib/http-server'
const app = express()
var io = require('socket.io').listen(HTTPServer);
```

But both threw the same 404 error on the client.

**So my question is, given my http server implementation, how do I set-up socket.io in `app.js`?**

EDIT 1:

The http object is created in `index.js`, with the following line

```
httpServer.create(httpConfig)
```

I have also tried my above attempts in this file with this object but still get the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my own problem, I needed to do the socket initialisation in the external js file, like so

```
import http from 'http'
import app from '../lib/app'

class HTTPServer {
    constructor(app) {
        this.app = app
    }

    create(options) {
        this.server = http.createServer(this.app)

        this.server.on('error', err => {
            console.log(`HTTP:   ${err}`)
            throw err
        })

        this.server.listen(options.port)

        const io = require('socket.io')(this.server);

        io.on('connection', (socket) => {
            console.log("connected")
            io.emit('hello', "hello world")
        })

    }
}

export default new HTTPServer(app)
```